How to integrate AvaloniaUI with camera video streams on Linux
I know that using window handles on Linux is very troublesome, so I want to display the yuv12 format stream output by the camera directly. My device is a hikvision camera, which is accessed directly through ip and other parameters.what is the best solution to display camera video in Linux using avaloniauui. It is best to control the rendering size and position by yourself

Please [edit] your question and copy&paste ypur code as a [mre] instead of describing your code. Answering a question about "the best solution" would be opinion-based. You should ask about specific problems. Add error messages or error codes.
